# XSLT using variable in for-each select

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to supply a dynamic name to a for-each select and cannot seem to get it to work.

My template is intended to allow a specific tag name to be passed in and then those nodes are selected from the xml and used for processing.

```
<xsl:param name="tagName" select="'DefaultTag'" />

<xsl:variable name="DataSource" select="document('../xml/datasource.xml')"/>

<xsl:template name="ProcessData">
    <xsl:for-each select="$DataSource//$tagName/DataValue" >

        ... Data operations here ...

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If I replace the $tagName in the for-each select with a hard-coded value then it works (for that value).

How do I get the variable substitution to happen using the param value?

Thanks,
-Dennis

Comment: What happens if you simply remove the single quotes around `DefaultTag`? Otherwise, please post a complete XSLT stylesheet so that people can test themselves.

Comment: How are you setting the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use variables like this in xpath to generate "dynamic" expressions, but in this case the variable part is just a single element name so you can filter using a predicate:

```
$DataSource//*[local-name() = $tagName]/DataValue
```

Comment: Perfect!  That was it.   I knew there had to be a way ...

Thanks!

Comment: @DennisButtery Please accept this answer (mark the tick on the left so that it appears in green). This is common practice on Stackoverflow.